# Regarding formatting of an html page in a symmetrical way

Tags: html

I am developing an html page , the html code is ...

```
<html>
<head>
<title> aaa</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="helloServlet">
<br>Pinpad security Code Genrator.</br>
<br></br>
Store No. <input type="text" name="txtName"><br></br>
Register No.
<input type="Generate" >
<br><input type="submit" value="Generate">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is ...

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/av1xc.jpg/

I want an alignment should be the and symmetrical should be the outlook , Please advise how to achieve that..!

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but I believe the answer is that you need to apply some style (css) to your html. Maybe you could post a picture of how you want things to be "aligned"? - as I don't understand the line "I want an alignment should be the and symmetrical should be the outlook"

Comment: Consider using the [label tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) for input labels and [fieldset/legend tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp) for the form title.

Comment: learn how CSS works. It is the only proper solution

Answer (score 1):

In CSS do **form { margin: 0 auto; }**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> aaa</title>
<style>
   form { margin: 0 auto; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="helloServlet">
<br>Pinpad security Code Genrator.</br>
<br></br>
Store No. <input type="text" name="txtName"><br></br>
Register No.
<input type="Generate" >
<br><input type="submit" value="Generate">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean but I'm guessing what you want is for the input fields to line up above one another. There is several ways to do so but the easiest (but not the preferred one) would be to put the form elements in a table, like this:

```
<form method="get" action="helloServlet">
<table>

<tr>
<td>Pinpad security Code Genrator.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Store No.</td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtName"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Register No.</td>
<td><input type="Generate" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Generate"></td>
</tr>

</form>
```

A more preferable way to do this would be using CSS. Then you can use position, left, top, bottom and right to position the elements by hand or you can arrange the elements to float into the right place by controlling the size and float behavior of the elements around. Something like:

```
<!-- In head -->
<style type="text/css">
label
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>

<!-- In body -->
<form method="get" action="helloServlet">
<div>Pinpad security Code Genrator.</div>

<div>
<label>Store No.</label>
<input type="text" name="txtName">
</div>

<div>
<label>Register No.</label>
<input type="Generate" >
</div>

<div>
<input type="submit" value="Generate">
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: using tables for layout in current era of html5 and CSS is a terrible starting point for anyone learning how layouts work

Comment: Yes table-layouts are horrible, thus I provided a CSS alternative as well, but they are much simpler to understand for a newcomer so I will have to disagree with you on this one.

Answer (score -1):

This will align the `form` in `center`

```
<html>
<head>
<title> aaa</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="helloServlet">
    <br>
    <center>Pinpad security Code Genrator.</center>
<br>
<center>Store No. <input type="text" name="txtName"></center><br>
<center>Register No.<input type="Generate" ></center>
<br>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Generate"></center>
</form>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated in html5. Use CSS

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML table tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> aaa</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="helloServlet">
<br>Pinpad security Code Genrator.</br>
<br></br>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Store No.</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtName"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Register No.</td>
    <td><input type="Generate"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Generate"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```